# how to refresh HideWhen formulas on views

Tags: lotusscript

i have soft delete enabled database and i store these deleted documents into a view named 'DeletedDocuments'
i have an action on this view to delete the soft-deleted documents permenantly...
i have a HideWhen formula on the action stating that the action should hide when the view does not contains any documents

following is ma lotusscript for action bar

```
Function deleteSelectedDocuments As Boolean
    deleteSelectedDocuments=False
    Call setObjectVars()
    Dim documentCollection As NotesDocumentCollection
    Dim userChoice As Integer

    On Error Goto errHandler

    Set documentCollection=gDB.UnprocessedDocuments

    If documentCollection.Count=0 Then
        Msgbox "You have not selected any documents. Please choose some to delete em",,"No documents selected"
    Else 

        userChoice=Msgbox ("Do you want to delete " & Cstr(documentCollection.Count) & " document(s)?",64+100, _
        "Please confirm...")

        If userChoice=6 Then
            Call documentCollection.RemoveAll(True)
            Call gWk.ReloadWindow()
            Call gWk.ViewRefresh
        End If
    End If

    deleteSelectedDocuments=True
    Exit Function
errHandler:
    Print "Error ***" & Error & " occured on line ***" & Cstr(Erl) & "*** with error number ***" & Cstr(Err)  & "*** while attempting to delete selected documents"
    Msgbox "Error ***" & Error & " occured on line ***" & Cstr(Erl) & "*** with error number ***" & Cstr(Err)  & "*** while attempting to delete selected documents"
    Exit Function
End Function
```

i want to refresh my view once the documents are deleted and want to refresh HideWhen formulas too...
i got something like uiDoc.RefreshHideFormulas
but uiDoc doesnt work here...
nor am i able to use @Command( [RefreshHideFormulas] ) in 'eveluate'...
how do i go about it????

Comment: I haven't tested this, but what about: Call notesUIWorkspace.ReloadWindow()

Comment: See my answer below- is that property checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call

@Command([ [RefreshHideFormulas](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_REFRESHHIDEFORMULAS.html) ]);

after the `gWk.ViewRefresh`.
You can use [Evalute](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-The_Evaluate_statement/) for that.

Comment: but could u tell me how do i write evalute method because @Command do not work in the Evaluate method.

Comment: Did you even take a look at the link behind "Evaluate"? There are code examples galore.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Evaluate actions for every document change" view property on the DeletedDocuments view. If it's not checked, the Hide-When for the view action will only evaluate when the view is opened.